Magento Cache is getting bigger and bigger after upgrade to 2.4.6-p6
I upgraded from Magento community editon 2.4.6-p3 to -> p4 -> p5 -> p6 (one after another on one day).
Since then I see that the cache is getting bigger and bigger. For example I made a tar backup before the upgrade which was about 6 GB. Two days later it was about 7 GB, and then three days more it was about 10 GB. When I flush the cache by "php bin/magento c:f" it takes very long time (I cant really say because the ssh session expiers), then its ok again.
Does anybody else have these problems? I know there was an issue on a earlier Magento version (where a workaround was to disable Magento_CSP, but this can not be disabled now because 2.4.6-p6 has this in restriction mode on the checkout).
I hope somebody have a fix for this.
Thank you!
